# DataTables column visibility modal not rendering with Bootstrap enabled

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I've setup a basic DataTables example using the column visibility button. This works fine when Bootstrap isn't enabled, but when it is the modal showing the list of columns does not work, see example shown in JSfiddle, i.e. removing this makes the button work as expected, but it won't work with Bootstrap.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/easynow/9yt0o6js/3/

Answer (score -1):

Answer helpfully provided on the datatables forum: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/74303/column-visibility-button-doesnt-seem-to-work-with-bootstrap-5#latest

Comment: Link-only answers are not considered valuable on SO. Please see [answer].